# ContentChildren with ng-template generates ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError inside component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular application, and I've faced this `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` a few times, but this time I don't know what to do to solve it.

I have a component that has a few child components using `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren`. Inside the child component, there is a list of children, all of which I'm rendering using `*ngTemplateOutlet`.

I've recreated the situation with an example based on a `TableComponent` that has a `HeaderComponent`, which can have multiple `HeaderItemComponent` inside, and a `QueryList` of `RowItem`.

I've made a StackBlitz with the full code to reproduce the error at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ieqh7

The weird thing to me is that, if I remove the header when rendering the table, no errors occur, even though the header items are rendered the exact same way as the rows.

Error occurs:

```
<table>
  <table-header>
    <table-header-item>Id</table-header-item>
    <table-header-item>Name</table-header-item>
    <table-header-item>Status</table-header-item>
  </table-header>

  <table-row *ngFor="let row of tableData">
    <table-row-item>{{ row.id }}</table-row-item>
    <table-row-item>{{ row.name }}</table-row-item>
    <table-row-item>{{ row.status }}</table-row-item>
  </table-row>
</table>
```

No errors:

```
<table>
  <table-row *ngFor="let row of tableData">
    <table-row-item>{{ row.id }}</table-row-item>
    <table-row-item>{{ row.name }}</table-row-item>
    <table-row-item>{{ row.status }}</table-row-item>
  </table-row>
</table>
```

Finally, the error, accused in line 2 of `header.component.html`:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngTemplateOutlet: undefined'. Current value: 'ngTemplateOutlet: [object Object]'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that error by wrapping your headers item inside setTimeOut

> [For More Info About Check this:](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/)

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    setTimeout(()=>{
         this.headerItems = this.inputHeaderItems.toArray();
        this.inputHeaderItems.changes.subscribe((value: QueryList<HeaderItemComponent>) => {
          this.headerItems = value.toArray();
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
      })

      }
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Every time I've seen `setTimeout` as a workaround, rather than a solution, but I'll just take it.

Also, I've tried implementing it in other manners but they didn't work, but this one did work.